# Cannot use object of type Profile as array

Tags: views

Write a script to filter content by country.

> I have problem Cannot use object of type Profile as array in .... on line 19

Part of code with error

```
global $user;
$country = "";
if($user->uid!=1 && $user->uid!=0){
  $user_full = profile2_by_uid_load($user->uid);
  if(!empty($user_full['client'])){
    $country_parent = taxonomy_get_parents($user_full['client']->field_clcountry['und'][0]['tid']);
```

Answer (score 3):

This

```
$user_full = profile2_by_uid_load($user->uid);
```

Returns an object, which you are then accessing as an array:

```
$user_full['client']
```

Which is illegal in PHP. You should access objects as objects, e.g.

```
$user_full->client
```

Or whatever it might be for that object type.

Comment: Thanks, Script is work without error now, but function of filtration is missing. Here it full code of script, please anybody help. http://pastebin.com/9rgcTF39

Comment: Please ask another question, and include the relevant portions of code, error messages, descriptions of what you're trying to achieve, etc

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this to load profile2

```
global $user;
$country = "";
if($user->uid!=1 && $user->uid!=0){
    $user_full = profile2_load_by_user($user);
    if(!empty($user_full['client'])){
        $country_parent = taxonomy_get_parents($user_full['client']->field_clcountry['und'][0]['tid']);
```